# Raspberry pi pico rfid rc522 (Micropython)

Tags: raspberry-pi, rfid, spi, micropython

I want to read data from mfrc522 (Iduino RFID-rc522) card reader using my RPi Pico but I don't know how to. I was trying to use mfrc522.py MicroPython library made for this purpose. Reader is communicating with Pi over SPI and I connected it to SPI0.
Code on pi:

```
    import time
from machine import I2C, Pin, SPI

from mfrc522 import MFRC522

sck = Pin(6, Pin.OUT)
mosi = Pin(7, Pin.OUT)
miso = Pin(4, Pin.OUT)
spi = SPI(0, baudrate=100000, polarity=0, phase=0, sck=sck, mosi=mosi, miso=miso)
sda = Pin(5, Pin.OUT)
rst = Pin(22, Pin.OUT)

while True:
    rdr = MFRC522(spi, sda, rst)
    uid = ""
    (stat, tag_type) = rdr.request(rdr.REQIDL)
    if stat == rdr.OK:
        (stat, raw_uid) = rdr.anticoll()
        if stat == rdr.OK:
            uid = ("0x%02x%02x%02x%02x" % (raw_uid[0], raw_uid[1], raw_uid[2], raw_uid[3]))
            print(uid)
```

And Library:

```
from machine import Pin, SPI
from os import uname


class MFRC522:

    OK = 0
    NOTAGERR = 1
    ERR = 2

    REQIDL = 0x26
    REQALL = 0x52
    AUTHENT1A = 0x60
    AUTHENT1B = 0x61

    def __init__(self, spi, cs, rst):

        self.spi = spi
        self.cs = cs
        self.rst = rst
        self.rst.value(0)
        self.cs.value(1)
        self.spi.init()
        self.rst.value(1)
        self.init()

    def _wreg(self, reg, val):

        self.cs.value(0)
        self.spi.write(b'%c' % int(0xff & ((reg << 1) & 0x7e)))
        self.spi.write(b'%c' % int(0xff & val))
        self.cs.value(1)

    def _rreg(self, reg):

        self.cs.value(0)
        self.spi.write(b'%c' % int(0xff & (((reg << 1) & 0x7e) | 0x80)))
        val = self.spi.read(1)
        self.cs.value(1)

        return val[0]

    def _sflags(self, reg, mask):
        self._wreg(reg, self._rreg(reg) | mask)

    def _cflags(self, reg, mask):
        self._wreg(reg, self._rreg(reg) & (~mask))

    def _tocard(self, cmd, send):
        recv = []
        bits = irq_en = wait_irq = n = 0
        stat = self.ERR

        if cmd == 0x0E:
            irq_en = 0x12
            wait_irq = 0x10
        elif cmd == 0x0C:
            irq_en = 0x77
            wait_irq = 0x30

        self._wreg(0x02, irq_en | 0x80)
        self._cflags(0x04, 0x80)
        self._sflags(0x0A, 0x80)
        self._wreg(0x01, 0x00)

        for c in send:
            self._wreg(0x09, c)
        self._wreg(0x01, cmd)

        if cmd == 0x0C:
            self._sflags(0x0D, 0x80)

        i = 2000
        while True:
            n = self._rreg(0x04)
            i -= 1
            if ~((i != 0) and ~(n & 0x01) and ~(n & wait_irq)):
                break

        self._cflags(0x0D, 0x80)

        if i:
            if (self._rreg(0x06) & 0x1B) == 0x00:
                stat = self.OK

                if n & irq_en & 0x01:
                    stat = self.NOTAGERR
                elif cmd == 0x0C:
                    n = self._rreg(0x0A)
                    lbits = self._rreg(0x0C) & 0x07
                    if lbits != 0:
                        bits = (n - 1) * 8 + lbits
                    else:
                        bits = n * 8

                    if n == 0:
                        n = 1
                    elif n > 16:
                        n = 16

                    for _ in range(n):
                        recv.append(self._rreg(0x09))
            else:
                stat = self.ERR

        return stat, recv, bits

    def _crc(self, data):

        self._cflags(0x05, 0x04)
        self._sflags(0x0A, 0x80)

        for c in data:
            self._wreg(0x09, c)

        self._wreg(0x01, 0x03)

        i = 0xFF
        while True:
            n = self._rreg(0x05)
            i -= 1
            if not ((i != 0) and not (n & 0x04)):
                break

        return [self._rreg(0x22), self._rreg(0x21)]

    def init(self):

        self.reset()
        self._wreg(0x2A, 0x8D)
        self._wreg(0x2B, 0x3E)
        self._wreg(0x2D, 30)
        self._wreg(0x2C, 0)
        self._wreg(0x15, 0x40)
        self._wreg(0x11, 0x3D)
        self.antenna_on()

    def reset(self):
        self._wreg(0x01, 0x0F)

    def antenna_on(self, on=True):

        if on and ~(self._rreg(0x14) & 0x03):
            self._sflags(0x14, 0x03)
        else:
            self._cflags(0x14, 0x03)

    def request(self, mode):

        self._wreg(0x0D, 0x07)
        (stat, recv, bits) = self._tocard(0x0C, [mode])

        if (stat != self.OK) | (bits != 0x10):
            stat = self.ERR

        return stat, bits

    def anticoll(self):

        ser_chk = 0
        ser = [0x93, 0x20]

        self._wreg(0x0D, 0x00)
        (stat, recv, bits) = self._tocard(0x0C, ser)

        if stat == self.OK:
            if len(recv) == 5:
                for i in range(4):
                    ser_chk = ser_chk ^ recv[i]
                if ser_chk != recv[4]:
                    stat = self.ERR
            else:
                stat = self.ERR

        return stat, recv

    def select_tag(self, ser):

        buf = [0x93, 0x70] + ser[:5]
        buf += self._crc(buf)
        (stat, recv, bits) = self._tocard(0x0C, buf)
        return self.OK if (stat == self.OK) and (bits == 0x18) else self.ERR

    def auth(self, mode, addr, sect, ser):
        return self._tocard(0x0E, [mode, addr] + sect + ser[:4])[0]

    def stop_crypto1(self):
        self._cflags(0x08, 0x08)

    def read(self, addr):

        data = [0x30, addr]
        data += self._crc(data)
        (stat, recv, _) = self._tocard(0x0C, data)
        return recv if stat == self.OK else None

    def write(self, addr, data):

        buf = [0xA0, addr]
        buf += self._crc(buf)
        (stat, recv, bits) = self._tocard(0x0C, buf)

        if not (stat == self.OK) or not (bits == 4) or not ((recv[0] & 0x0F) == 0x0A):
            stat = self.ERR
        else:
            buf = []
            for i in range(16):
                buf.append(data[i])
            buf += self._crc(buf)
            (stat, recv, bits) = self._tocard(0x0C, buf)
            if not (stat == self.OK) or not (bits == 4) or not ((recv[0] & 0x0F) == 0x0A):
                stat = self.ERR

        return stat
```

My output is absolutely clear and I am not getting any print. Where's my problem?

Comment: at first, i do see problem in your pins declaration. You define all pins as output. You do not need that. see example here: https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp32/quickref.html#software-spi-bus

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After straggling with this problem too and posting an unuseful answer which was deleted, i finally managed to get it work. Take a look at this thread at [raspberry.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=303249), especially at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/danjperron/micropython-mfrc522) from danjperron mentioned there.

I copied the code to my Pico and changed the pin numbers in *examples/Pico_read.py*, line 11 to `reader = MFRC522(spi_id=0,sck=6,miso=4,mosi=7,cs=5,rst=22)` to match your used pins. It will print out something like `Card detected 0C9B5023` if it works.

Answer (score 2):

The miso is an input to the pico.  Try changing the miso pin assignment to miso = Pin(4, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)