# Can't use MFRC522 with Raspberry Pi Pico W

Tags: microcontroller, rfid, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am unable to interface the MFRC522 module with a Raspberry Pi Pico W. I followed [this explanation](https://microcontrollerslab.com/raspberry-pi-pico-rfid-rc522-micropython/). It doesn't work for me. I tried replacing wires and soldering the headers but nothing works. Is it a software issue?

Main.py:

```
import time
from machine import I2C, Pin, SPI

from mfrc522 import MFRC522

sck = Pin(2, Pin.OUT)
mosi = Pin(3, Pin.OUT)
miso = Pin(4, Pin.OUT)
spi = SPI(0, baudrate=100000, polarity=0, phase=0, sck=sck, mosi=mosi, miso=miso)
sda = Pin(1, Pin.OUT)
rst = Pin(0, Pin.OUT)

while True:
    rdr = MFRC522(spi, sda, rst)
    uid = ""
    (stat, tag_type) = rdr.request(rdr.REQIDL)
    print(stat)
    if stat == rdr.OK:
        (stat, raw_uid) = rdr.anticoll()
        if stat == rdr.OK:
            uid = ("0x%02x%02x%02x%02x" % (raw_uid[0], raw_uid[1], raw_uid[2], raw_uid[3]))
            print(uid)
```

[Different code I tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66194810/raspberry-pi-pico-rfid-rc522-micropython/66535832).

Comment: I don't know if there are other issues, but MISO (master-in-slave-out) is an input to the master, not an output. You have `miso = Pin(4, Pin.OUT)`.

Comment: Unfortunately I updated that detail and it still gives me the same result. When I output the stat it is still a 2 meaning an error

Comment: Probably best to get a logic analyser or oscilloscope to see what the SCK, MISO and MOSI signals are doing. And the sda signal, which I think is really SS.